# Unity Probem on playing!! how can i resolve?

Tags: unity-game-engine

**When ever I play the game in Unity Editor it pauses for a minute and shows this screen:**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj7RH.png)

and after a while the starts

Unity editor version: 2020.3.1f1 LTS

Comment: can you attach the error ("Could not load signature [..]") as text?, this way we can actually read the error message and try to help you. The error message probably explains what the issue is. so 1) read it and 2) attach it, and 3) show us you did read it (what do you understand about it, what don't you)

Comment: I have had and resolved this error in the past i think. Can you elaborate one how your project is using firebase, and what other libraries/SDK's you are using? (it's relevant)

Answer (score 0):

Since I believe I have had and resolved this issue before, but there is a lot of missing information in your question, which could help me remember the answer, this first "answer" is probably wrong, but there not much more one can answer, than "try to do this"

so here we go:

1. go to menu "Assets/play service resolver/ios[or android]/install cocoapos[or resolve].

And try again. You might have to install the External dependency resolver package via the unity package manage

2. might follow once you post more info ;)